# how to use csvHelper to read the second line in a csv file

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I have a csv file with two lines, the first one is the header line, which includes 36 columns separated by `,`

The second line is the values, which are 36 value separated by `,`

I want to read the second line, I found that all people talk about [csvHelper package](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper), so I download it, but it doesn't have any `dll` to add to my project.

my question is how to include it and how to read the second line.

I know that I can install it using `Install-Package CsvHelper` but I don't want that way because I want to deploy this application on a server. Thus, I would prefer If there is a way like `add reference` or something.

if i knew how to include it, reading the second line wouldn't be hard.
I would do something like this:

1. load the csv file
2. read the first line and ignore it.
3. read the second line and split it by `,`.

Comment: You could use `StreamReader.ReadLine()` to skip the first line.

Comment: "I know that I can install it using `Install-Package CsvHelper` but I don't want that way because I want to deploy this application on a server" What on earth are you talking about? You can't deploy projects to a server that use nuget package manager? We do this on an almost daily basis.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I don't know about it because I am not good in c#. However, thanks for mentioning it to me. Plus, my problem is not in reading the csv file, my problem is in including that library, which I search for it a lot in Google but couldn't find anything helpful to me.

Comment: `Install-Package` *does* add a reference. And a bit of package bookkeeping behind the scenes. You still have a normal project you can deploy.

Comment: @spender I mean that I don't want to tell that customer that he needs to fire this statment `Instal-Package CsvHelper`. it is a windows application. so I need the customer, who have the server bty, to just double click on the application and the application runs. I hope you got me and I am sorry if I wrote something very stupid. I am not a good developer.

Comment: @Joey if that is the case, why the have a zip for download? I thought that this zip would include the .dll that I have to include. anyway, are you saying that if I used the install-package, I will have the .dll to add to my vs2012 project?

Comment: @AgnieszkaPolec Basically nuget will download the dll, copies it in local and add the reference for you. So technically you downloading the dll and adding reference also same. All you have to do is make sure all the dlls are in place while you deploy it to server.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel many thanks, I just realized that. I will try to use that install-package and update you.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel when I did this `PM> Install-Package CsvHelper` I got these results:
`Installing 'CsvHelper 2.7.0'. Successfully installed 'CsvHelper 2.7.0'. Adding 'CsvHelper 2.7.0' to MyProjectName. Successfully added 'CsvHelper 2.7.0' to MyProjectName.` now should I do anything else when deploying the app on the customer server? or that is enough and the library will be included by default? thanks a lot

Comment: @AgnieszkaPolec Looks good, added successfully. Now build your application, go to `bin\debug` folder, you'll find one more extra dll presumably `CsvHelper.dll`. You need to copy that dll along with your exe while deploying.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could use `TextReader.ReadLine()` to skip the first line:

```
using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText("filename"))
{
    reader.ReadLine();
    // now initialize the CsvReader
    var parser = new CsvReader( reader ); // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have about 200 csv file. So, I thought that csvHelper has a way to read them all. right?

Comment: @AgnieszkaPolec: i'm not familiar with that parser, so i've looked at the documentation. http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/ But i think that it will be helpful anyway. Also, i don't understand the difficulty to parse 200 files once you know how to parse one.

Comment: Thanks for your update, I am trying to install that package. Then I will test your code and update you. +1 for your efforts with me.

Comment: in your code you passed the first line, which is the header, to the csv reader right?

Comment: @AgnieszkaPolec: as the documentation states [`TextReader.ReadLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) reads and returns the next line, then it advances the reader to the next line. I do nothing with that line since i only want to skip this line. Then i pass the reader to the constructor of the `CsvReader` which now will just parse all lines except the first.

Answer (score 14):

**The accepted answer is a workaround for the problem, but the library has the first-class solution for this common case** 
`CsvConfiguration` class has a property `HasHeaderRecord` which could be set to `true`, this will cause the library to skip the first line in the file.

```
CsvConfiguration configuration = new CsvConfiguration { HasHeaderRecord = true };

using (TextReader sr = new StringReader(fileContent))
{
    CsvReader reader = new CsvReader(sr, configuration);
}
```

here is a snippet of the [Documentation](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/api/CsvHelper.Configuration/Configuration/)

> Gets or sets a value indicating if the CSV file has a header record. Default is true.

**UPDATE** in the newer version of the library the class `CsvConfiguration` is just renamed to `Configuration`

Comment: Why are you setting is true if it is already true by default?

Comment: I answered this question very long ago, maybe at that time, it was not the default value. On the other hand, the question is asking explicitly about that, which means that for some reason it did not work(maybe because it is an old version of the library). Last for someone how to search for this problem this means he has problem and he need solution, this could help him